# error C2248: 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'

Tags: c++

Getting this error and I'm pretty sure it's in the operator<< function. Both prints are public.

```
void CRational::print() const
{
    print(cout);
}

void CRational::print(ostream & sout) const
{
    if(m_denominator == 1)
        cout << m_numerator;
    else
        cout << m_numerator << "/" << m_denominator;
}

ostream operator<<(ostream & sout,const CRational a)
{
    a.print();

    return sout;
}

CRational operator++() // prefix ++x
{
    m_numerator += m_denominator;
    return *this;
}

in main:
cout << "e before: " << e << ", \"cout << ++e\" : " << ++e << " after: " << e << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I got a new problem. When I go to use this function the numbers print out backwards in the way that recursion works.

Answer (score 12):

You need to return the ostream by reference, not value. Its trying to call a constructor.
Might as well pass 'a' as reference as well:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream & sout,const CRational& a)
```

I also note that the print method is probably wrong. It has `sout` passed as the name of the stream but is then implemented using `cout` directly. It should be

```
void CRational::print(ostream & sout) const
{
    if(m_denominator == 1)
        sout << m_numerator;
    else
        sout << m_numerator << "/" << m_denominator;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
ostream operator<<(ostream & sout,const CRational a)
       ^ You are trying to return by value
```

Streams are not copyable, so you can't return one by value.  You need to return the stream by reference (`std::ostream&`).

Also, you should probably be outputting to `sout` in your `CRational::print(ostream&)` function (otherwise, why take it as an argument?) and you should probably be passing `sout` when you call `a.print()` in your `operator<<` overload (otherwise, the overload doesn't really do what an idiomatic `operator<<` overload for a stream is supposed to do).

Answer (score 2):

`operator<<` should return a reference to an `ostream`: `ostream& operator<<`...

Also your functions are kinda messed up. Instead of using `cout`, you should used the passed in `ostream` which you've named `sout`.